# adding limit for a models choices in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model for order status, this model creates a table with a foreign key to order model and saves a status for order ( like pending, accepted, failed, sending and received ) and a time of the status added

it is auto generate in with pending when the order is created and other ones have an API with post method for each order

now, I wanna limit the choices for API in this form:
If there is a pending status when getting order status list the choices need to limited to accepted and failed

If there is a accepted status when getting order status list the choices need to limited to sending and received

If there is a failed status when getting order status list the choices need to limited to pending and accepted

If there is a sending status when getting order status list the choices need to limited to received

this is the order status model:

```
class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='status')
    ORDER_STATUS_PENDING = 'P'
    ORDER_STATUS_ACCEPTED = 'A'
    ORDER_STATUS_FAILED = 'F'
    ORDER_STATUS_SENDING = 'S'
    ORDER_STATUS_RECEIVED = 'R'
    ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (ORDER_STATUS_PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (ORDER_STATUS_ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
        (ORDER_STATUS_FAILED, 'Failed'),
        (ORDER_STATUS_SENDING, 'Sending'),
        (ORDER_STATUS_RECEIVED, 'Received')
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES, default=ORDER_STATUS_PENDING)
    status_change = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

this is the order status serializer:

```
class OrderStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_id = self.context['order_id']
        return OrderStatus.objects.create(order_id= order_id, **validated_data)
    class Meta:
        model = OrderStatus
        fields = ['id','payment_status', 'status_change']
```

this is the order status view:

```
class OrderStatusViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrderStatusSerializer
    
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in ['POST', 'DELETE']:
            return [IsAdminUser()]
        return [AllowAny()]
        
    def get_serializer_context(self):
         return {'order_id': self.kwargs['order_pk']}

    def get_queryset(self):
         return OrderStatus.objects.filter(order_id = self.kwargs['order_pk'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Django has support for `limit_choices_to` in foreign key relations.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to
This field can accept callable as per example in the documentation. Version 3.9.1 is supposed to support this attribute: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#391

In my opinion, your solution would be to use callable on limit_choices_to attribute on the model filed, that will limit the choices to your needs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyIPAoq80tY - this might also help you.